# Font conflict between Noto Color Emoji and Arabic in Doom Emacs

Tags: linux, emoji, arch

In Doom Emacs I have this setting that allows me to set this particular font only to Arabic characters.

```lisp
(set-fontset-font t 'arabic "Noto Naskh Arabic")
```

Here's a visual representation (notice the emojis in the Qtile bar):

[image: Noto Naskh Arabic font display]

However, when I install the Noto Color Emoji, it overrides my setting in Emacs:

[image: Noto Color Emoji display]

Removing the font reverts me to the prior state.
I don't know if the issue can be fixed in the system or in Emacs' settings, which is why I'm posting here.

I'm on ArcoLinux.

Comment: Different fonts display chars differently; that's all. This has nothing to do with Emacs, if I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Adding a font in my system should not change a font set in emacs' settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ttf-joypixel, no conflict with that emoji font.